# WPF Popup has a black border instead of a transparent one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, popup

I am programmatically creating a popup for an element in a WPF window and can't get rid of the black border:

[image: Popup with border]

```
var p = new Popup {
     PlacementTarget = target,
     IsOpen = true,
     StaysOpen = false,
     AllowsTransparency = true
};

// Add the popup content
p.Child = new Views.MapLocationInformation {DataContext = context};
```

The User control `MapLocationInformation` is defined in XAML like this:

```
<UserControl ...
 mc:Ignorable="d" 
 Background="Transparent"
 d:DesignHeight="65" d:DesignWidth="401">

 <Border BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="5"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderBorderGradient}"
        Background="White"
        Margin="0 0 8 8">

        <Stackpanel> ... </Stackpanel>
     </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I cannot find any combination of border, background fill and transparency setting which would render the black area transparent. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the border does not belong to your MapLocationInformation control?  What happens when you put a red rectangle as the child?

Comment: I've added the user control definition and will play around with alternative content. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem. The problem appers to be, that when the Popup's `IsOpen` Property is to `True` too early, the transparency is not working properly.

My Solution was to move setting `IsOpen` to true from the contruction to the `Loaded` event of the Popup.

```
myPopup.Loaded += (sender, args) => { myPopup.IsOpen = true; };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Popup allows transparency but is not using a transparent background. Change to:

```
var p = new Popup {
     PlacementTarget = target,
     IsOpen = true,
     StaysOpen = false,
     AllowsTransparency = true,
     Background = Brushes.Transparent
};
```

That should do the trick. Also, the reason the black bit is wider on the right and bottom is due to the `Margin` on your `Border`, which is actually kind of useless. I suggest you remove that too.

Comment: There is no any background property in wpf for popup.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `Background` property of `MapLocationInformation`. Just set the `Background` of your `UserControl` to null and `AllowsTransparency` to `True` to fix it, like this:

```
<UserControl ...
 mc:Ignorable="d" 
 Background="{x:Null}"
 AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Answer (score 0):

@NikoR is right. But it is just the order of the properties.

You must set `AllowsTransparency` **before** `IsOpen`:

```
var popup = new Popup
{
  AllowsTransparency = true,
  IsOpen = true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I needed to add was `AllowsTransparency = true` for the `Popup`. I have a feeling [Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991300/3195477) is correct, and the inclusion of a nonexistent Background property there is not relevant because it is not needed.